# mysql join duplicates - works fine on table2 but adding table3 duplicates table2s rows

Tags: mysql

so, I'm using proprietary data, so I can't just cut paste my code in here.
and, I'm sorry this is probably trivial, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around why it's duplicating.

so, I have 4 tables

table 1
did, vid, sid, cid

table 2
vid, vname

table 3
sid, date, value

table 4
cid, date, value

what I'm trying to achieve is
table1. did, table2.vname, table3.sid, table3.date, table3.value, table4.cid, table4.date, table4.value

if I do

```
    select table1.did, table2.vname, table3. . .
    from table 1
    join table 2 on table2.vid = table1.vid
    join table 3 on table3.sid = table1.sid and table3.date > now() - interval 1 year
    where table1.did = 1
    ;
```

I get exactly what I want.

```
    table1.did, table2.vname, table3.sid, table3.date, table3.value
    1,               blah,         123,    2013-3-1,        123
    1,               blah,         123,    2013-2-1,        3234
    1,               blah,         123,    2013-1-1,        111111     
    1,               blah,         123,    2012-12-1,       122222     
    1,               blah,         123,    2012-11-1,       155341     
    1,               blah,         123,    2012-10-1,       102002
```

then:

```
    select table1.did, table2.vname, table3. . ., table4. . .
    from table 1
    join table 2 on table2.vid = table1.vid
    join table 3 on table3.sid = table1.sid and table3.date > now() - interval 1 year
    join table 4 on table4.cid = table1.cid and table4.date > now() - interval 1 year
    where table1.did = 1
    ;
```

gives me:

```
    t1.did, t2.vname, t3.sid, t3.date, t3.value, t4.cid, t4.date, t4.value
    1,       blah,     123,   2013-3-1,  123,    456,    2013-3-1,   1112345     
    1,       blah,     123,   2013-3-1,  123,    456,    2013-2-1,   234
    1,       blah,     123,   2013-3-1,  123,    456,    2013-1-1,   2
    1,       blah,     123,   2013-2-1,  3234,   456,    2012-12-1,  332111     
    1,       blah,     123,   2013-2-1,  3234,   456,    2012-11-1,  5432
    1,       blah,     123,   2013-2-1,  3234,   456,    2012-10-1,  555
```

Anyway I can prevent the duplicates when I  join the 4th table?
if I switch 3rd and 4th it works the same way, so its definitely something to do with how I'm joining them all together.

Thanks for helping!

*** EDIT / workaround ***

I've found what I feel is a clunky way to do this.  I'm posting it as an answer, because I know it works.  But if someone knows a better way to do this, I'll mark that as the accepted answer.

add a new table called 'days'

data:

```
    day_id, dateYMD,    dateUS,      dateEU,      dayName
    1,      1970-01-01, 01/01/1970,  01/01/1970,  Thursday
    2,      1970-01-02, 01/02/1970,  02/01/1970,  Friday
    3,      1970-01-03, 01/03/1970,  03/01/1970,  Saturday
    . . .
    . . .
    . . .
    735322, 2013-03-30, 03/30/2013,  30/03/2013,  Saturday
    735323, 2013-03-31, 03/31/2013,  31/03/2013,  Sunday
    735324, 2013-04-01, 04/01/2013,  01/04/2013,  Monday
```

and then changed my query as such:

```
    select table1.did, table2.vname, date_format(days.dateYMD, '%Y-%m-01') as daysYMD, table3. . ., table4. . .
    from table 1
    join days on days.dateYMD > now() - interval 1 year and days.dateYMD <= now()
    join table 2 on table2.vid = table1.vid
    join table 3 on table3.sid = table1.sid and table3.date = date_format(days.dateYMD, '%Y-%m-01')
    join table 4 on table4.cid = table1.cid and table4.date = date_format(days.dateYMD, '%Y-%m-01')
    where table1.did = 1
    group by daysYMD
    ;
```

again, this did the job - but I'm wondering if anyone knows a better way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `group by t3.vid, t4.cid` to your last query.

```
  select table1.did, table2.vname, table3. . ., table4. . .
    from table 1
    join table 2 on table2.vid = table1.vid
    join table 3 on table3.sid = table1.sid and table3.date > now() - interval 1 year
    join table 4 on table4.cid = table1.cid and table4.date > now() - interval 1 year
    where table1.did = 1
    Gropu by t3.vid, t4.cid
```

Comment: That won't work because I need each date individual, If I group it by the id's I won't get the dates.

(I've tried

        group by t3.date, t4.date

too which doesn't change the results at all.)